# Passing a constexpr array from non-type parameter pack as template argument fails

Tags: templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I define an array from the parameter pack as constexpr. Then I want to pass this array as template argument to another template. However, I get an external linkage error. What is the problem here? I thought a constexpr can be easily forwarded as template parameter.

```cpp
// Example program
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template <size_t X>
using iMat1D = std::array<size_t, X>;

template <size_t SizeOfDims, const iMat1D<SizeOfDims> &DIMs>
struct test{
  static void run() {
  }
};

template <std::size_t... DIMS> 
struct solver_walker {
  static void run() {
    constexpr std::size_t N = sizeof...(DIMS);
    constexpr std::array<size_t, N> dims = {{DIMS...}};
    test<N, dims>::run();
  };
};

int main()
{
    solver_walker<1,2,3,4>::run();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a *reference* to `dims` as a template argument. As `dims` is not a `static` variable, this reference is not a *constant expression*.

You can solve this issue by making `dims` a `static` variable:

```
template <std::size_t... DIMS> 
struct solver_walker {
  static void run() {
    constexpr std::size_t N = sizeof...(DIMS);
    static constexpr std::array<size_t, N> dims = {{DIMS...}};
    test<N, dims>::run();
  };
};
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9tkdIXwPf3xfAlz0)